# IBM DB2 select query not getting executed

Tags: java, database, db2

Whenever I try to execute bellow query :

```
Select * from VEHICLE_INFO
```

I'm getting bellow exception

```
... Physical database connection acquired for: STAGBIG
 07:19:11  [SELECT - 0 rows, 0.002 secs]  1) [Code: -551, SQL State: 42501]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=HYUSER;SELECT;FNI.VEHICLE_INFO, DRIVER=4.19.49. 2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-551;42501;HYUSER|SELECT|FNI.VEHICLE_INFO, DRIVER=4.19.49
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 0.002/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 errors]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: SQLCODE -551 means that the user `HYUSER` does not have `SELECT` privileges for table `FNI.VEHICLE_INFO`, as the error message says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current user wan't having sufficient privileges. That is why facing the error.

Got required privilege and access now no more error.

Comment: Can you tell me how to granted privilege, and how can you revoke it again, exact commands you used.